# Answering a question with suggestions from other multiple answers

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

Is it OK to answer a question (your own or someone else's) if it already has answers, but the full answer requires the suggestions from multiple answers (with credit being given to the authors of the other answers)?

If the question requires both answers to solve it (and this is not referenced anywhere), is the new answer redundant or valid?

Here is an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493303/in-html-posting-a-form-with-javascript-and-php-validation-one-fault-return-tr/16496438#16496438

Comment: I do this sometimes, but adding stuff so it's not a redundant answer.

Comment: In this case it required both solutions to work, so does this make it redundant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the information is spread across multiple locations, consolidate it!

The main purpose of Stack Overflow existing is to have every answer to every programming problem. If a future Googler has to dig around multiple answer for a solution, then we aren't doing a very good job, are we?

I would say that you should merge the information into a new answer, mention what info was from who, and *certainly* give each contributor an upvote.

Comment: thnx Undo, yes I upvoted the other answers, but they were both for the same question, so not in different places. I couldn't get the code working without both answers however and they were pointing to different issues. please advise (best if you have a look at the answer)

Comment: @Yve I would still say that you should merge them. If the end Googler has to do anymore work than look at one answer, we have failed. Just merge them and move on :)

Comment: In the referenced situation, I would say you did the right thing.

Comment: Thanks undo. I will mark the question as answered shortly